# Hierarchical Clustering using Centroids

Tags: clustering, centroid, data-mining

Perform a hierarchical clustering (with five clusters) of the one-dimensional set of points $2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23$ assuming clusters are represented by their centroid (average) and at each step the clusters with the closest centroids are merged.

I begin with every point in its own cluster, i.e. $\left\{2\right\},\left\{3\right\},\left\{5\right\},\left\{7\right\},\left\{11\right\},\left\{13\right\},\left\{17\right\},\left\{19\right\},\left\{23\right\}$
I then know that the distance between any 2 clusters is the Euclidean distance between their centroids and we merge the 2 clusters at the shortest distance.
However Im not sure how to calculate the centroids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cluster centroid $c$ of a cluater $C = \{v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_{|C|}\}$ is usually defined as
$$
c = \frac{1}{|C|} \sum_{i=1}^{|C|} v_i
$$
That is, it is the mean of the points.

Comment: So would the final answer be: $\left\{2,3\right\}, \left\{5,7\right\}, \left\{11,13\right\}, \left\{17,19\right\}, \left\{23\right\}$? This seems too simple as it is found after 1 step

Comment: @SophieFiler Note that in each iteration, we merge only the closest two groups.